# Domain Issue: Notation

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

**Problem**

Given Hilbert spaces $\mathcal{H}$ and $\mathcal{K}$.

Consider an operator:
$$A:\mathcal{D}A\subseteq\mathcal{H}\to\mathcal{K}$$

> It is well known that:*
>   $$A=A^{**}\iff A\in\mathcal{C}(\mathcal{H},\mathcal{K})$$

Consider an operator:
$$P:\mathcal{D}P\subseteq\mathcal{H}\to\mathcal{H}$$

> Then does it follow:
>   $$P^2=P=P^*\implies P\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$$

Consider an operator:
$$J:\mathcal{D}J\subseteq\mathcal{H}\to\mathcal{K}$$

> And does it follow:
>   $$JJ^*J=J\implies J\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H},\mathcal{K})$$

How can I check these?

**Closed, dense operators:* $\mathcal{C}(\mathcal{H},\mathcal{K})$

**Context**

Given Hilbert spaces $\mathcal{H}$ and $\mathcal{K}$.

Consider a closed operator:
$$A:\mathcal{D}A\subseteq\mathcal{H}\to\mathcal{K}:\quad A=A^{**}$$

Then it admits some:
$$J:\mathcal{D}J\subseteq\mathcal{H}\to\mathcal{K}:\quad J|A|\varphi:=A\varphi$$

But is it also chosen:
$$\mathcal{D}J=\mathcal{H}:\quad\|J\|<\infty$$

> Now the above applies:
>   $$J^*J=1_{\overline{\mathcal{R}|A|}}\implies J\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H},\mathcal{K})$$

That would shorten notation.

Comment: Can someone tell why it is off-topic, please? Thanks! :) *(I will improve it then.)*

Comment: Please, post only one question in one post. Posting several questions in the same post is discouraged and such questions may be put on hold, see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6464/posting-multiple-questions-as-one?). Besides, none of your three questions have any kind of context.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Ah k thanks alot!! Can you explain what kind of context is desired? *(For example to 'shorten notation'?)*

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960 I don't understand what you mean by "That would shorten notation": what notation?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: Ah ok; let me outline it in the question.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: I added a motivation. *(Hope this makes it clearer.)*

Comment: Besides splitting the assertions into two separate threads wouldn't make much sense here - at all!! OR?! *(Note these are guideless to improve not to rule.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Meanwhile I got it...*

**Projection**

They have domain:
$$\mathcal{D}(P^*P)=\mathcal{D}(P^2)=\mathcal{D}P$$

So it must be bounded:
$$\|P\varphi\|^2=\langle P^*P\varphi,\varphi\rangle=\langle P\varphi,\varphi\rangle\leq\|P\varphi\|\cdot\|\varphi\|$$

Also dense and closed:
$$P=P^*=P^{**}\implies P=\overline{P}\quad(\overline{\mathcal{D}P}=\mathcal{H})$$

By closed graph theorem:
$$\|P\|<\infty:\quad P=\overline{P}\implies\mathcal{D}P=\overline{\mathcal{D}P}$$

Concluding projection.

**Partial Isometry**

It gives rise to:
$$P:=J^*J:\quad P^2=P=P^*$$

So it has full domain:
$$\mathcal{H}=\mathcal{D}P=\mathcal{D}(J^*J)\subseteq\mathcal{D}J\subseteq\mathcal{H}$$

Its modulus is bounded:
$$J^*J=P\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})\implies\sqrt{J^*J}=\sqrt{P}\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$$

Thus itself is bounded:
$$\|J\varphi\|^2=\langle J^*J\varphi,\varphi\rangle=\langle\sqrt{J^*J}\varphi,\sqrt{J^*J}\varphi\rangle=\|\sqrt{J^*J}\varphi\|^2\leq\|\sqrt{J^*J}\|^2\|\varphi\|^2$$

Concluding partial isometry.